# Insert Whole CSV File in a MySql Table Row

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to store all the contents of a CSV file into a table row.

Table structure:

```
Field   Type   Comment
id      bigint(15) NOT NULL  Primary key for table
file_id bigint(15) NULL      Reference key from filemapper table
file_content longtext NULL    Content of the File
dataTime  timestamp NOT NULL
```

Problem arises when I try to do insert in this table with a CSV file, I get an Error "***MySQL server has gone away***".

**I am not trying to split the csv file fields into columns in mysql table**

Can anyone suggest another way to do this without causing the error?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file

Comment: @JakeB. thanks a lot. I thought that wouldn't be the case with my issue as the Error Code was 2013 not 2006 which was mentioned in that question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql server has gone away while storing large (2MB) audio file in LONGBLOB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492429/mysql-server-has-gone-away-while-storing-large-2mb-audio-file-in-longblob)

Answer (score 2):

```
MySQL server has gone away has foolwing causes and sollutions.
1.Server time out and closed the connection.To fix,check that "wait_timeout" mysql variable in your my.conf Coonfiguration file is large enough or not.
2.Server dropped an incorrect or too large pocket.If mysqld gets a packet that is too large or incorrect it assumes that something gone wrong with connection and connection closed.To fix this problem increase maximal packet size limit "max_allowed_packet" in my.conf file e.g. set  max_allowed_packet = 128M 
You Can GO to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file
```

Answer (score 0):

for fixing this thing you have to increase the maximal packet size limit

```
MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET
```

in .cnf file for eg:

```
max_allowed_packet = 128M
```

Restart

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Using   [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) you can do that.

you need to set fields `TERMINATED BY`

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

your syntax should looks like this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ‘path/to/example.csv’ INTO TABLE example FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’ IGNORE 1 LINES ;
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I am not trying to split the csv file fields into columns in mysql table